# Performing side effects using scala cats effect

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I'm trying to use cats effect in scala and in the end of the world I have the type:
`IO[Vector[IO[Vector[IO[Unit]]]]]`

I found only one method to run it:

```
for {
    row <- rows.unsafeRunSync()
} yield
 for {
   cell <- row.unsafeRunSync()
 } yield cell.handleErrorWith(errorHandlingFunc).unsafeRunSync()
```

But it looks pretty ugly. Please help me to understand how I can perform complex side effects.

UPDATE:

1)First `IO` - I open excel file and get the vector of rows i.e `IO[Vector[Row]]`.

2)Second `IO` - I perform query to DB for each row. I can't compose IO monad with `Vector[_]`,

3)Third `IO` - I create PDF file for each row from excel using `Vector[Results]` from DB.

So I have such functions as:

1) `String=>IO[Vector[Row]]`

2) `Row=>IO[Vector[Results]]`

3) `Vector[Results] => IO[Unit]`

Comment: Just look at the cats documentation itself.

Comment: How do you end up with `IO[Vector[IO[Vector[IO[Unit]]]]]`? I would expect a situation with

` for { a <- thingReturningIOUnit ; b <- thingReturningIOVector1; c <- thingReturningIOVector2 } yield ... `

Comment: ending up with a nested `IO` is the very indication that you should learn more abut `IO` before proceeding.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I'm not sure "just read the docs" is very useful advice here. This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Why not? First IO - I open excel file and get the vector of rows i.e IO[Vector[Row]], second IO - I perform query to DB for each row. I can't compose IO monad with Vector[_],  third IO - I create PDF file for each row from excel using Vector[Results] from DB. So I have such functions as  String=>IO[Vector[Row]], Row=>IO[Vector[Results]], Vector[Results] => IO[Unit]

Comment: Your case is clearer to me now. Thanks.

Comment: Btw superb (as always) answer by Travis.

Comment: Generally speaking, I see `IO` as being similar to `Future` when it comes to requirement semantics. So, requirement-wise an `IO[Vector[IO[Vector[IO[Unit]]]]]` is pretty similar to `Future[Vector[Future[Vector[Future[Unit]]]]]`. And I am very sure, you don't want to see that in your code and more importantly you don't require to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of example here's a nonsense action I've just made up off the top of my head with the same type:

```
import cats.effect.IO

val actions: IO[Vector[IO[Vector[IO[Unit]]]]] =
  IO(readLine).flatMap(in => IO(in.toInt)).map { count =>
    (0 until count).toVector.map { _ =>
      IO(System.nanoTime).map { t =>
        (0 until 2).toVector.map { _ =>
          IO(println(t.toString))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here we're reading a string from standard input, parsing it as an integer, looking at the current time that many times, and printing it twice each time.

The correct way to flatten this type would be to use `sequence` to rearrange the layers:

```
import cats.implicits._

val program = actions.flatMap(_.sequence).flatMap(_.flatten.sequence_)
```

(Or something similar—there are lots of reasonable ways you could write this.)

This program has type `IO[Unit]`, and works as we'd expect:

```
scala> program.unsafeRunSync
// I typed "3" here
8058983807657
8058983807657
8058984254443
8058984254443
8058984270434
8058984270434
```

Any time you see a deeply nested type involving multiple layers of `IO` and collections like this, though, it's likely that the best thing to do is to avoid getting in that situation in the first place (usually by using `traverse`). In this case we could rewrite our original `actions` like this:

```
val actions: IO[Unit] =
  IO(readLine).flatMap(in => IO(in.toInt)).flatMap { count =>
    (0 until count).toVector.traverse_ { _ =>
      IO(System.nanoTime).flatMap { t =>
        (0 until 2).toVector.traverse { _ =>
          IO(println(t.toString))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This will work exactly the same way as our `program`, but we've avoided the nesting by replacing the `map`s in our original `actions` with either `flatMap` or `traverse`. Knowing which you need where is something that you learn through practice, but when you're starting out it's best to go in the smallest steps possible and follow the types.

Comment: Your answer is really a brilliant! I've opened the new side of cats library ) I mean https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html